# Rename specific tab in a workbook based on cell value with illegal character

Tags: excel, vba

I have a  workbook with sheets but a specific sheet named "final" that sheet need to be rename based on cell value B2 which has an illegal character in it e,g "CHEVROLET/ZZ"

Tried code below , but code are for all sheets .

changed all sheets instead of specific sheet "final"

```
Sub tabname()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        On Error Resume Next

        If Len(ws.Range("B2")) > 0 Then    
            ws.Name = ws.Range("B2").Value
        End If

        On Error GoTo 0

        If ws.Name <> ws.Range("B2").Value Then
            MsgBox ws.Name & " Was Not renamed, the suggested name was invalid"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

e,g "CHEVROLET/ZZ" in   cell B2  in "final" sheet tab.

only sheettab "final" to be  rename as "CHEVROLET-ZZ" as final results

Comment: Is this the only illegal character you expect to see or can it vary?

Comment: the only characters are "\" or "/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to trim the intended name, replace 7 forbidden characters and cut it to the allowed maximum of 31 characters:

```
Private Function NewTableName(ByRef IntendedName As String) As String
    Dim s As String
    s = Application.Trim(IntendedName)
    s = Replace(s, ":", "-")
    s = Replace(s, "\", "-")
    s = Replace(s, "/", "-")
    s = Replace(s, "?", "-")
    s = Replace(s, "*", "-")
    s = Replace(s, "[", "-")
    s = Replace(s, "]", "-")
    NewTableName = Left(s, 31)
End Function
```

At last: You get an error, if you try to rename a second worksheet with an already existing worksheet's name. So you should check its existence before.