# show details for each pivot item in new sheet and change its name

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to:

1. Create a drill down table for each visible company in the pivot table on a new sheet.
2. Rename the sheet with the company name.

The code I have seems to work until I apply a filter to the pivot table.

```
Sub Test1()

    Dim pField As PivotField
    Dim pItem As PivotItem

    Set pField = Sheets("PivotTable").PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Company")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each pItem In pField.PivotItems
    If pItem.Visible Then
        pItem.DataRange.ShowDetail = True
        ActiveSheet.Name = pItem.Name
        End If
    Next pItem

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Background on `PivotItem.Visible`**

If you filter a `PivotTable` then some of your `Rowfields` or `ColumnFields` show less `PivotItems`.

Unfortunately each corresponding `PivotField.PivotItem` is still returned as `Visible`, even if you don't see it.
Also `PivotField.VisibleItems.Count` is not reduced.

**Addressing "really" visible PivotItems**

Filtering a `PivotTable` changes the visible `DataRange` of a `PivotField`, so you can loop over its cells and use the cell's value to identify each visible `PivotItem`:

```
Dim pItemCell As Range
For Each pItemCell In pField.DataRange
    If pItemCell.Value <> "(blank)" Then
        Set pItem = pField.PivotItems(pItemCell.Value)
        pItem.DataRange.ShowDetail = True
        ActiveSheet.Name = pItem.Name
    End If
Next pItemCell
```

You may also loop over each `PivotRowAxis.PivotLines().PivotLineCells().PivotItem`.
Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55444457/10908769

**Getting Details for the GrandTotals Column**

```
Dim pTable As PivotTable
Dim pField As PivotField
Dim i As Long

Set pField = Sheets("PivotTable").PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Company")
Set pTable = pField.Parent

If pTable.RowGrand = True Then
    For i = 1 To pField.DataRange.Cells.Count
        pTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, pTable.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count).ShowDetail = True
        ActiveSheet.Name = pField.DataRange.Cells(i).Value
    Next i
End If
```

**Hint for `ActiveSheet.Name`**

Please be aware, that there are restrictions for renaming a worksheet: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54620175/10908769

Comment: Hey Asger! I appreciate the help earlier and tip regarding the worksheet naming restrictions (I hadn't considered that) 

Anyways I am stuck again -- I'd like it to show the details of the total column currently it shows details of the first Item in the data range. I tried using .offset to move it over 9 columns to no avail.

Comment: Hey -- still stuck here. For anyone else reading -- this: [link](https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/) was pretty helpful for me in learning how pivot tables are referenced in VBA. But i'm still not sure how to tell it to show details on the total for each row.

Comment: Now I shortened it and hope it works for you. If yes, please mark it as answer.